# Excel VBA Sorting Function Outputs

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project in which I need to create an excel program that will guide agricultural producers to create a secondary containment for their fuel tanks. I have been working on a program and have a lot of it created, but ran into an issue. I have a section where if they have multiple tanks it will calculate the volume given the diameter and length. Here is a snippet of that code

```
    Option Explicit

Sub NoInput()
    Dim strInputDiameter As String
    strInputDiameter = Application.InputBox("Tank Diameter") 'get diameter inputs

    Dim strInputLength As String
    strInputLength = Application.InputBox("Tank Length") 'get length inputs

    'convert comma separated inputs to arrays of Doubles
    Dim dblDiameter() As Double
    dblDiameter() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputDiameter))
    Dim dblLength() As Double
    dblLength() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputLength))


    Dim rngCurrCell As Range
    Set rngCurrCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    'set number of containers to whichever input had the least values
    Dim intContainerCount As Integer
    intContainerCount = WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(dblDiameter), UBound(dblLength))

    'calculate volume for each container, output to sheet
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To intContainerCount
        rngCurrCell.Value = "Diameter " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = dblDiameter(i)

        rngCurrCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Length " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = dblLength(i)

        rngCurrCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Volume " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(2, 1).Value = calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter(i), dblLength(i))

        Set rngCurrCell = rngCurrCell.Offset(0, 3)
    Next i

Call Largest

End Sub

Function csv_to_string_array(strCSV As String) As String()
    csv_to_string_array = Split("," & strCSV, ",") 'don't know why, but needs a leading comma otherwise it skips the first input
End Function

Function str_to_double_array(strArray() As String) As Double()
    Dim tempDblArray() As Double
    ReDim tempDblArray(UBound(strArray))

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(strArray)
        tempDblArray(i) = CDbl(strArray(i))
    Next i

    str_to_double_array = tempDblArray()
End Function

Function calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter As Double, dblLength As Double) As Double
    calc_cylinder_volume = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() * ((dblDiameter / 2) ^ 2) * dblLength)
End Function

Sub Largest()
'Cells with dates also return a value, and get covered for determining largest value. Percentages will convert and return numerics.

Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMax As Double

'Set range from which to determine largest value
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z100")

'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

'Displays largest value
MsgBox dblMax


End Sub
```

I want to then use the maximum volume and solve a formula based on if it is a vertical or horizontal tank. The volume formula is different for a horizontal or vertical tank. I need a way that I can ask in the form of a msgbox if it is horizontal or vertical and then have that result attached to that tank. So e.g. Column one has: "Diameter: 12 Length: 12 Orientation: Vertical".Column Two has: "Diameter: 8 Length: 12 Orientation: Horizontal". Once I know the orientation of the tank then I can determine the proper volume formula I need to use to then solve an equation.

Comment: Re: `'don't know why, but needs a leading comma otherwise it skips the first input` - `Split` returns a 0 based array.  Your loops start at index 1.

Comment: If you are just wanting the user to enter the orientation of, say, the 5th tank you could just have an InputBox with a message saying `"What is the orientation of tank" & TankNo`.  If you need to know the orientation of **all** the tanks, you could get the info when you are asking for the diameters and lengths (i.e. just another InputBox with comma-delimited input [probably just "H"s and "V"s, to make it easier for the user to type]).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. Here is the code. It may not be pretty (Not a great coder by trade, a bit of a better engineer though) , but it works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub NoInput()
    Dim strInputDiameter As String
    strInputDiameter = Application.InputBox("Tank Diameter") 'get diameter inputs

    Dim strInputLength As String
    strInputLength = Application.InputBox("Tank Length") 'get length inputs

    Dim strInputOrientation As String
    strInputOrientation = Application.InputBox("Orientation")

    'convert comma separated inputs to arrays of Doubles
    Dim dblDiameter() As Double
    dblDiameter() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputDiameter))
    Dim dblLength() As Double
    dblLength() = str_to_double_array(csv_to_string_array(strInputLength))
    Dim strOrientationArray() As String
    strOrientationArray() = Split(strInputOrientation, ",")


    Dim rngCurrCell As Range
    Set rngCurrCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    'set number of containers to whichever input had the least values
    Dim intContainerCount As Integer
    intContainerCount = WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(dblDiameter), UBound(dblLength))

    'calculate volume for each container, output to sheet
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To intContainerCount
        rngCurrCell.Value = "Diameter " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = dblDiameter(i)

        rngCurrCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Length " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = dblLength(i)

        rngCurrCell.Offset(2, 0).Value = "Volume " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(2, 1).Value = calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter(i), dblLength(i))

        rngCurrCell.Offset(3, 0).Value = "Orientation " & i
        rngCurrCell.Offset(3, 1).Value = strOrientationArray(i - 1)

        Set rngCurrCell = rngCurrCell.Offset(0, 3)
    Next i

Call Largest

End Sub

Function csv_to_string_array(strCSV As String) As String()
    csv_to_string_array = Split("," & strCSV, ",") 'don't know why, but needs a leading comma otherwise it skips the first input
End Function

Function str_to_double_array(strArray() As String) As Double()
    Dim tempDblArray() As Double
    ReDim tempDblArray(UBound(strArray))

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(strArray)
        tempDblArray(i) = CDbl(strArray(i))
    Next i

    str_to_double_array = tempDblArray()
End Function

Function calc_cylinder_volume(dblDiameter As Double, dblLength As Double) As Double
    calc_cylinder_volume = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() * ((dblDiameter / 2) ^ 2) * dblLength)
End Function

Sub Largest()
'Cells with dates also return a value, and get covered for determining largest value. Percentages will convert and return numerics.

Dim rng As Range
Dim dblMax As Double

'Set range from which to determine largest value
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z100")

'Worksheet function MAX returns the largest value in a range
dblMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

'Displays largest value
MsgBox dblMax


End Sub
```